# ADDON or SHARED_ADDON Path in PyroCMS

Tags: codeigniter-2, pyrocms

Im writing a module for PyroCMS,

I need to get the directory of my module that has been installed so I can load an image on the browser.

The image is stored beneath the libraries folder in my module.

I would like to do something like

```
$logo =  $this->get_addon_path(). '/libraries/myfile.png';
```

Which should return either of these values

```
www.mysite.com/addons/mysite/modules/mymodule/libraries/myfile.png
www.mysite.com/shared_addons/modules/mymodule/libraries/myfile.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find this solution in the code of another program
Id thought id share it.

```
$this->module_details['path']
```

For me I just needed to wrap it up like so

```
base_url() . $this->module_details['path'].'/libraries/gateways/'.$image_name;
```

Which returns

```
www.mysite.com/addons/mysite/modules/mymodule/libraries/gateways/myfile.png
```

Comment: if there is a better solution I will mark it as the correct answer, but for now this seems to solve my problem.

Comment: well you can define a constant for this in constant.php so that you don't have to write it like the above method